# How to export to CSV the Hash of each file (SHA-256 & MD5) that are inside a folder in Windows?

Tags: powershell, hash, md5, sha256

I receive files from the client and I need to make sure those files are healthy even after I process these files.
What I want to beware of is a situation of possible tampering with already processed files.
A customer error may occur for sending files with missing information and the customer wants to edit the original file to say the information was there.
That's why I had the idea of ​​producing a report with the hash of these files that are in the reception directory.
I tried hard to make everything clearer and more intelligible, even though I didn't speak English.

*Scene 1:*
I have a directory with several text files and I need to export the SHA-256 and MD5 hash calculations from each file to a CSV somewhere.

*Scene 2:*
I have a directory with several subfolders with customer names and within these customers, other subfolders.  How to extract SHA-256 & MD5 Hash from all files in these directories and subdirectories?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm sure you've read the help topics about [Ask]. If not I'd recommend to do so now. ;-)

Comment: Real. Regards @Olaf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should get you started. This finds the SHA256 hash for every file inside the current directory (not including subdirectories)

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-FileHash | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\summary.csv"
```

```
PS C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code> cat "C:\Temp\summary.csv"
#TYPE Microsoft.Powershell.Utility.FileHash
"Algorithm","Hash","Path"
"SHA256","8E8FF02948E62C54EF782373500CD0D97B8A2DA0F1655A6134B37284CF5BCE79","C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191201.in"
"SHA256","63E68322B7E8131CDDEFB77492EC7E1B8B8C46696772CE561850C854E4E8B6EA","C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191201.py"
"SHA256","FFF1D3F7F7FBDDC4CDC90E123D9BC7B0B7A450DC28F3A4F2D786701B4A9B279D","C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191204.py"
"SHA256","DE3662893F2779446AFC78B20E63F5250826D5F52206E5718E1A2713F876941E","C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191206.in"
"SHA256","B9381E11A442DDC8CF802F337F0487E9269800B145106FFDDB0E6472D8C6F129","C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191206.py"
```

If you really need both SHA256 and MD5:

```
$h = @(Get-ChildItem | Get-FileHash)
$h2 = ($h | Get-Item | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5)  
for ($i=0; $i -lt $h.Length; $i++) { 
    $h[$i] = [PSCustomObject]@{Path=$h[$i].Path; SHA256=$h[$i].Hash; MD5=$h2[$i].Hash} 
}
$h | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\expo.txt"
```

```
PS C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code> cat "C:\Temp\expo.txt"
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Path","SHA256","MD5"
"C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191201.in","8E8FF02948E62C54EF782373500CD0D97B8A2DA0F1655A6134B37284CF5BCE79","11689BA3058C306DAA3651562621BE20"
"C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191201.py","63E68322B7E8131CDDEFB77492EC7E1B8B8C46696772CE561850C854E4E8B6EA","3F50E29C797ED4BD65122F8DA1208D4D"
"C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191204.py","FFF1D3F7F7FBDDC4CDC90E123D9BC7B0B7A450DC28F3A4F2D786701B4A9B279D","41094A3E067669F46C965D0E34EA5CA6"
"C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191206.in","DE3662893F2779446AFC78B20E63F5250826D5F52206E5718E1A2713F876941E","1A7571873E6B9430A2BFD846CA0B8AB7"
"C:\Users\Jan\Dropbox\py\advent_of_code\20191206.py","B9381E11A442DDC8CF802F337F0487E9269800B145106FFDDB0E6472D8C6F129","0CBB058D315944B7B5183E33FC780A4D"
```

Comment: I was also needing this solution for a project I'll be doing this summer, so glad to already have the answer.  But Thiago is wanting both SHA-w56 & MD5.  I think I know how to do that, either  Select-Object rename (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-change-output-object-property-names-with-powershell/), or maybe build a new psObject with new members, and then feed it into Export-CSV.  Is that something you are up to writing?  If not, I may try it.

Comment: @Darin I added an answer for both SHA256 and MD5 now (even though I don't really know why you would need that). I don't really think it makes sense to put more effort into this as the question just is not clear.

Comment: @xjcl Don't you feel like you just did someones homework now? ;-)

Comment: @Olaf It probably doesn't even help OP (the hashes they want might be inside of the files), plus I enjoyed the exercise being new to PowerShell

Comment: @xjcl, Thanks.  I'm half way through my own approach to answer this.  Will finish because because I also enjoy the exercise, but now no need to post it.  In my summer project, I may include the MD5, but not sure.  The old software we've been using for years is producing MD5 - so not sure if we want to have a mixed environment, or just convert everything to SHA.

Comment: You should be able to pipe `$h` directly to `Get-FileHash`, there shouldn't be a need to pipe it to `Select-Object` + `Get-Item`. This question didn't deserve an answer, but +1 for enjoying the PowerShell exercise :)

Comment: @Olaf, It's not any homework or project assigned to me.  I had this insight to guard against potential client dishonesty.  So I edited the question and description. (@xjcl)

Comment: @ThiagoSalvatico My comment actually was about your lack of own research and no code to share at all.

Comment: My Powershell does not have the Export-CSV Cmdlet - where can I get it?